# Can I work on a Rails project in a directory other than C:\Sites on Windows?

Tags: windows, ruby-on-rails

I'm a beginner to Rails.

I installed Rails using RailsInstaller for Windows.

Is `C:\Sites\` a magic directory path or can I still use the Rails framework in a directory like `C:\Documents...\Dropbox\project`? I want to be able to work between two different computers on the same project.